# Gathering, averaging, and resulting

Tags: r

Greetings to you all good people,

I am looking at the math and science scores for different countries that OECD-PISA publishes. While I am looking at the different scores that different students achieved, I found a row that has the following name "Selected countries and jurisdictions". After searching the name, I found an answer in "The Early Advantage: Building Systems That Work for Young Children" book. This row represents average scores by a group of students from selected countries [1.Australia, 2.England, 3. Findland, 4.Hong Kong, 5.the Republic of Korea, 6.Singapore].

Let us say that I have the following cross country data,

```
year  country          GDP_growth   R&D_exp  Education_spending
2000  Australia        3.4          1.9      4.8
2001  Australia        2.1          0.9      5.0
2002  Australia        3.0          0.9      6.2
2000  England          3.6          3.9      7.8
2001  England          3.5          4.6      7.8
2002  England          3.2          4.0      7.9
2000  Findland         1.9          0.2      8.0
2001  Findland         2.2          0.7      8.1
2002  Findland         2.7          1.0      8.2
```

My question: how can I gather GDP growth, R&D ependiture, ... for these selected countries, calculate the average, and add the result in a new row for each year?  I want to do the mentioned step for all years (2000 to 2018).

So, by the end, I will have new rows have the name "Selected countries and jurisdictions" for different years that have the final results (aggregated and averaged) as the following:

```
year     country                                GDP_growth  R&D_exp    Education_spending
2000     Selected countries and jurisdications   3.5         3.1        6.1
2001     Selected countries and jurisdications
...
```

Kindly share your ideas and thoughts about how such a thing could be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `aggregate()`. For selection, simply use a `country.set` vector. Beforehand it's wise to use [syntactically valid names](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html), which you can achieve with `make.names()`.

```
names(dat) <- make.names(names(dat))

country.set <- c("Australia", "England")

cbind(aggregate(cbind(GDP_growth, R.D_exp, Education_spending) ~ year, 
          dat[dat$country %in% country.set, ], mean), 
      country="Selected countries and jurisdications")[c(1, 5, 2:4)]  # some ordering
#   year                               country GDP_growth R.D_exp Education_spending
# 1 2000 Selected countries and jurisdications        3.5    2.90               6.30
# 2 2001 Selected countries and jurisdications        2.8    2.75               6.40
# 3 2002 Selected countries and jurisdications        3.1    2.45               7.05
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L), country = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"England", "England", "England", "Findland", "Findland", "Findland"
), GDP_growth = c(3.4, 2.1, 3, 3.6, 3.5, 3.2, 1.9, 2.2, 2.7), 
    `R&D_exp` = c(1.9, 0.9, 0.9, 3.9, 4.6, 4, 0.2, 0.7, 1), Education_spending = c(4.8, 
    5, 6.2, 7.8, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `aggregate()` + `cbind()`

```
select_crt <- c("England","Findland")
dfout <- cbind(aggregate(cbind(GDP_growth, R.D_exp, Education_spending)~year,subset(df,country %in% select_crt), FUN = mean),select_crt = toString(select_crt))
```

or

```
select_crt <- c("England","Findland")
dfsel <- subset(df,country %in% select_crt)
dfout <- cbind(aggregate(dfsel[-c(1:2)],dfsel[1], FUN = mean), select_crt = toString(select_crt))
```

and both of them will give you

```
> dfout
  year GDP_growth R.D_exp Education_spending        select_crt
1 2000       2.75    2.05               7.90 England, Findland
2 2001       2.85    2.65               7.95 England, Findland
3 2002       2.95    2.50               8.05 England, Findland
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L), country = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"England", "England", "England", "Findland", "Findland", "Findland"
), GDP_growth = c(3.4, 2.1, 3, 3.6, 3.5, 3.2, 1.9, 2.2, 2.7), 
    R.D_exp = c(1.9, 0.9, 0.9, 3.9, 4.6, 4, 0.2, 0.7, 1), Education_spending = c(4.8, 
    5, 6.2, 7.8, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using dplyr/tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df$country_n <- "Selected countries and jurisdications"
df <- df %>% 
      group_by(year, country_n) %>% 
      summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% 
      rename(country = country_n)
```